# ExtJS 5: Set child View Model data from bound value

Tags: javascript, extjs, mvvm, extjs5

I have a class that has its own view model, and I create 2 instances of this class in my main view. In the main view, I want to pass down values for my 2 class instances, but I can't seem to get this working... I think I'm just not understanding some very simple concept.

The expected result is the **value1 + value2** field has the concatenation of value1 and value2, the first myValue shows value1, and the 2nd myValue shows value2. Here's my code and [example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/t1a):

```
Ext.application({
  name: 'Fiddle',

  launch: function() {
    Ext.define('MyViewModel', {
      extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
      alias: 'viewmodel.myView',
      formulas: {
        doSomething: function(getter) {
          console.log(getter('value1'), getter('value2'));
          return getter('value1') + getter('value2');
        }
      }
    });

    Ext.define('MyView', {
      extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
      xtype: 'myView',
      viewModel: {
        type: 'myView'
      },
      config: {
        myValue: null
      },
      publishes: {
        myValue: true
      },
      items: [
        {
          xtype: 'displayfield',
          fieldLabel: 'myValue',
          bind: {
            value: '{myValue}'
          }
        }
      ]
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {
      renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
      items: [
        {
          xtype: 'displayfield',
          fieldLabel: 'display',
          bind: {
            value: '{doSomething}'
          }
        },
        {
          xtype: 'myView',
          reference: 'view1',
          title: 'View1',
          bind: {
            myValue: '{value1}'
          }
        },
        {
          xtype: 'myView',
          reference: 'view2',
          title: 'View2',
          bind: {
            myValue: '{value2}'
          }
        }
      ],
      viewModel: {
        data: {
          value1: 'Something',
          value2: 'something else'
        }
      }
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: Why do you think that your `Ext.container.Container` instance will use `MyViewModel`? Specify `type: 'myView'` in its `viewModel` config and see the difference. Similarly, how can you expect `myView` bindings to use data from the parent's viewmodel if they have their own one?

Comment: I actually don't expect my container to use MyViewModel... I did, however, specify its own local viewModel with my two data values.  I was hoping that I could somehow hand down a parent's bound data to the children, but I guess that's not possible?

Comment: That's all possible, but that will make your design more tightly coupled. The "best practice" solution will depend on your *actual* goal. For example, maybe there is no need for `myView` instances to have their own viewmodels and they can use the parent's one?

Comment: Well that's the thing, I want to be using this class in other views, so I basically want to prevent copy and pasting code all over the place.  I was just hoping I could feed it a parent's bound variable... guess I was totally wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first displayField will never "see" the doSomething formula, because that formula is not part of it's parent, so you will need to move the formula from `MyViewModel` to your `Ext.container.Container` viewModel.

Also, when you publish a custom value, it will have `reference.publishedvalue` format. This should fix your panel:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {
        Ext.define('MyViewModel', {
            extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
            alias: 'viewmodel.myView'
        });

        Ext.define('MyView', {
            extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
            xtype: 'myView',
            viewModel: {
                type: 'myView'
            },
            config : {
                myValue : null
            },
            publishes : ['myValue'], 
            items: [{
                xtype: 'displayfield',
                fieldLabel: 'myValue',
                initComponent : function() {
                    var me = this,
                        owner = me.$initParent || me.initOwnerCt;

                    this.setBind({
                        value: '{' + owner.reference + '.myValue}'
                    });
                    this.callParent();
                }
            }]
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            viewModel: {
                data: {
                    value1: 'Something',
                    value2: 'something else'
                },
                formulas: {
                    doSomething: function(getter) {
                        console.log(getter('value1'), getter('value2'));
                        return getter('value1') + getter('value2');
                    }
                }
            },
            items: [{
                xtype: 'displayfield',
                fieldLabel: 'display',
                bind: {
                    value: '{doSomething}'
                }
            },{
                xtype: 'myView',
                reference: 'view1',
                title: 'View1',
                bind: {
                    myValue: '{value1}'
                }
            },{
                xtype: 'myView',
                reference: 'view2',
                title: 'View2',
                bind: {
                    myValue: '{value2}'
                }
            }]
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Haha, duh!  That's what happens when I make an example in haste... I knew there was something strange about `doSomething` not working.  But what I really care about is what you're doing with the `setBind` in the `initComponent`.  I'm actually surprised there's not a better way of doing this.

Comment: If you want to skip the whole reference thing, you can force a two way bindable, check this fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/t1h

Comment: You're totally right... I had figured two-way binding was set up when I used the combination of `config`, `publish`, and `bind`.  I forgot I had to set up an actual method for custom properties.  Man, that was a dumb mistake.  Thanks.

Comment: The publishes config is used to publish the value of a config, while what you wanted was to get a value from the viewModel data. Adding a field to the config block makes it possible for you to add it to the bind block. It can be confusing sometimes but read this carefully: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.mixin.Bindable-cfg-publishes

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't mean to drag this on anymore, but I'm curious... what if my class was a textfield... is it possible to set the data from the parent view model (like you've already done for me), but also update the parent view model with what gets entered in the textfield?  I guess this goes beyond two-way binding.  If there's not a simple answer, don't bother... I can work something out on my own.

Comment: Humm..can you provide a fiddle (fiddle.sencha.com) with what your saying? It's hard to visualize what you are trying to do just by reading comments :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88249/discussion-between-incutonez-and-guilherme-lopes).